# Angular responsive form, updating control with array value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to update the value of an array in a form control. Simply clearing it out and attempt to set a new value results in an error. Based on other SO answers I'm attempting change values directly via a loop. I don't get errors but the values don't update:

```
  const voltage = this.dynamicValues.controls.voltage;

  this.voltageItems.sort();

  this.voltageItems.forEach((volt, i) => {
    const control = new FormControl(volt);
    if (voltage.value[i]) {
      (voltage as FormArray)[i] = control;
    } else {
      (voltage as FormArray).push(control);
    }
  });

  this.addComponentForm.updateValueAndValidity();
```

`this.dynamicValues` is a `formGroup` of controls, one of which is voltage. `this.voltageItems` is just an array of the selected voltages. Finally, `this.addComponentForm` is the parent `formGroup` that holds the other groups and controls. I've tried placing the `updateValueAndValidity` against `this.dynamicValues` but that didn't resolve the issue.

The initial value set by the `(voltage as FormArray).push(control);` sets fine, no issues, but the value isn't updating with the `(voltage as FormArray)[i] = control;`

If I log `(voltage as FormArray)[i]` after setting the new value it shows with the new value instead of what was originally set by the `(voltage as FormArray).push(control);` but it's not reflecting that in the form.

logging out `voltage` or `this.dynamicValues.controls.voltage` both show the original values as though the `foreach` never ran.

Comment: try `voltage.push(control);` instead of ` (voltage as FormArray).push(control);`

Comment: @indrajeet the push is working as expected when setting the data initially

Answer (score 0):

SO as i understood you have `addComponentForm` is parent form group and inside `addComponentForm` you have `dynamicValues` is another form group and inside this i assume you have `voltage` as form array(as you are trying to push inside). Please look at following code which worked for me.

```
addComponentForm: FormGroup;
  voltageItems = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.addComponentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     dynamicValues: this.formBuilder.group({
                         voltage: this.formBuilder.array([]) 
                    }),
      otherControl: [''] 
    });

    const voltage = this.addComponentForm.get('dynamicValues').get('voltage');

   this.voltageItems.sort();

  this.voltageItems.forEach((volt, i) => {
    const control = new FormControl(volt);
    if (voltage.value[i]) {
      (voltage as FormArray)[i] = control;
    } else {
      (voltage as FormArray).push(control);
    }
  });

  console.log(this.addComponentForm);

  this.addComponentForm.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Really it's most simple that all this. If this.voltage is a FormArray and this.voltageItems an array of values (else, please updated the question with this data)

```
this.voltage=new FormArray(this.voltageItems.map(x=>new FormControl(x))

//or 
this.voltage.clear();
this.voltageItems.forEach(x=>{
    this.voltage.push(new FormControl(x));
})
```

A Form array is not only just an array of FormControls (or an array of FormGroups)